# Export from Google Docs to Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-docs

I am trying to automate an export of information received from a form and held on a spreadsheet into my Google+ page. Is this possible using only the Javascript that google has made available in these docs?

Answer (score 1):

The API for posting to a Google+ page is limited to select partners. You will not be able to automate posting to a Google+ Page.